# Elixir: functions call with underscore and assignment as parameters

Tags: elixir

What is the purpose of using _a = 5 instead of 5 in the code below? Is there a name for this technique?

```
def some_func(a) do
    IO.puts(a)
end

some_func(_a = 5)
```

Comment: It is likely a hint to the code reader. I personally don’t see any reason for that and I am not aware of it being named and/or widely used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the [Naming Conventions](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/naming-conventions.html#underscore-_foo):

> ### Underscore (`_foo`)
>
> Elixir relies on underscores in different situations.
>
> For example, a value that is not meant to be used must be assigned to
> `_` or to a variable starting with underscore:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> {:ok, _contents} = File.read("README.md")
> ```

There is a video of José Valim doing it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rFlhFbJ1_s&t=246s

He's writing the following [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) call:

```elixir
|> Enum.reduce({_depth = 0, _position = 0}, fn 
  {:forward, value} -> {depth, position} -> {depth, position + value}
  ...
end
```

Here the initial value of the accumulator is written as `{_depth = 0, _position = 0}`. The `_depth` and `_position` variables are not used, they are just hints to the developer. He could have written `{0, 0}` directly instead, but then it wouldn't be obvious what the integers referred to without checking the function implementation below.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening there is just a pattern matching between `_a` and `5` before properly calling `some_func`

the result of `_a = 5` is `5`.

the same happens with `a = 5` which is also `5`

and even for `5 = 5`, you guessed right, it is `5`.

so at the execution time what happens is

```
some_func(_a = 5) 
some_func(5)
```

Though this pre `_` usage is discouraged, besides in function declarations, as it's used to tell the compiler that the variable is indeed not used in the function body.

Comment: it is not discouraged if it is used in function declaration, you can use it to pattern match for example a map structure, in this form however it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Daniel well, it could be kinda poor man type hint (`convert(_value_radian = 3.14)`.)

Comment: indeed, however I would expect hints on the receiving side (function definiton), I know for sure that python had the problem with named parameters, I bet it comes from that infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I use that technique in this situation:

```
defmodule A do
  def compute(list, x), do: _compute(list, x, [])

  defp _compute([head|tail], x, acc) do
    #
    val = ...
    _compute(tail, x, [val|acc]) 
  end
end
```

and I'll write:

```
                                                |
                                                |
defmodule A do                                  V
  def compute(list, x), do: _compute(list, x, _acc=[])
```

in order to indicate to a beginner what the `[]` is.  But, in the example you posted where there is only one parameter variable, I don't think it clarifies anything.